# Magento 2: Paytm payment integration

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I want to Paytm payment integration. Please suggest me which is the better payment integration extension for India.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use official Module from Paytm.

Paytm has official Git repository for magento 2 module.

> https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Magento_Kit

You can check all available module for different CMS/eCommerce platform from Paytm at:

> https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/plugins/

Hope above will help!